# Replace all kind of dashes

Tags: php, str-replace

I have a excel document which I import in MySQL using a library.

But some of the texts in the document contain dashes which I though I have replaced, but apparently not all of them.
`-`, `–`, `-` <-all of these are different.

Is there any way I could replace all kind of dahes with this one `-`

The main problem is that I dont know all of the dashes that exist in computers.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I want to `explode()` that text.

Comment: And why do not use `str_replace(['-','–','-'], '-', $sData)` ?

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo because that's presumably not *all* of the dashes, although that should be sufficient if that's all the dashes in the documents she's having there. In other words, she doesn't need all the dashes that exist in computers but just all that exist in her documents.

Comment: I just want to make sure I'm not missing some.

Comment: @Gordon - I think it's up to topic starter to decides what symbols could be delimiters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use regex with unicode modifier `u` and a character class:

```
$output = preg_replace('#\p{Pd}#u', '-', $input);
```

[**From the manual**](http://www.php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.unicode.php) : `Pd Dash punctuation`

[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/bB7kW4)

Comment: [Unicode Characters in the 'Punctuation, Dash' Category](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pd/list.htm)

Comment: Thanks, that works fine so far. But how do I add space in this regex. All " - ", not "-" :)

Comment: @FakeHeal use `\s*\p{Pd}\s*`. Note that `\s*` will match whitespace zero or more times. Whitespace may be a normal space, tabs, newlines and more.

Comment: Simply brilliant. Exactly the thing I was looking for working with multi national partners who might have odd ideas to use varios dash chars as EAN/UPC/GTIN delimiters. This will trim them all, and leave only numbers, which is only thing valid in this business.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
$string = str_replace(array('-','–','-','—', ...), '-', $string);
```

Use the above code and see if it works. If you're still seeing some dashes not being replaced, you can just add them into the array, and it'll work.